# 4 вопроса по Bitrix и ни одного ответа. Как дальше жить?

Tags: обсуждение

Я в разное время задал 4 вопроса на SO, в основном по Bitrix, но не получил ни одного ответа и ни одного комментария, указывающего что вопрос не корректен. То же касается всех остальных форумов. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Смиритесь и пишите ответы сами как найдете решение. на мои вопросы люди смотрят "что за дичь - зачем он в это полез?" )

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking с большой вероятностью вы здесь найдёте ответ на свой вопрос или подчерпнёте что-то новое)

Answer (score 6):

Вы задаете вопросы, на которые сложно дать ответ, так как они не соответствуют правилам сайта. Это и есть "не так". Как этот, например  - мне пришлось самому искать ваши вопросы, вы тут даже ссылки не привели.

---

*Обновление к начальному ответу:*

Кроме того, даже получив этот ответ, вы за несколько дней на него не отреагировали:-) Всё в целом указывает на низкий интерес к собственным же вопросам и потребительское отношение к тем, кто предположительно должен отвечать.
Посмотрел все четыре ваших вопроса тут от последних к первым:

1. Вообще без кода, какие-то общие вопросы.
2. Есть код (написанный сложно для восприятия) и нет никакой информации о тестах, кроме "работает некорректно". Кто и как должен догадываться, что такое для вас корректно, а что некорректно? Приводите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь.
3. Код с вопросом без комментариев, в чем сложность у вас, и без ваших попыток. Воспринимается как "сделайте за меня".
4. Аналогично вопросу 3.

Comment: Если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если сильно понравилось:-)